SOQL write a query to find the 3rd least annualRevenue on account
eg: if I have the following annualRevenue in ascending order.
10
10
10
12
15
16
18
19
then I should get 15 as the output.

If you have duplicates I don't think there's an easy way because field 'AnnualRevenue' can not be grouped in a query call
Normally I'd try to play with something like this and then capping it with LIMIT, OFFSET but in this case it throws an error
SELECT AnnualRevenue, COUNT(Id)
FROM Account
GROUP BY AnnualRevenue
ORDER BY AnnualRevenue DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 5

You'll have to select top 10 or so and filter them out in the application code...

I have edited my question. can you please check again?

Doesn't change much, sort ASC instead of DESC but still will need some postprocessing in apex / external code that calls the SOQL.
